# select a range clicking a combo value in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to do a drop down list in a google sheets with months listed, when I click on one of the month, pointer should go at a specific range in the same sheet, for example if one clicks on November, focus should go in cells(8,233).
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to install an `onEdit` script like below. This is a bit brute force, but is very easy to understand and change.

In the example below I assumed the drop down is in `B7` (picked at random). This is row 7, col 2.

Depending on which month "jan" - "Dec" focus is switched to `B21` to `B32` respectively.

You can edit to code for wherever you put your drop-down, and wherever you want to change focus to.

```
function onEdit(event){
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

   var map ={'Jan':'B21',
            'Feb':'B22',
            'Mar':'B23',
            'Apr':'B24',
            'May':'B25',
            'Jun':'B26',
            'Jul':'B27',
            'Aug':'B28',
            'Sep':'B29',
            'Oct':'B30',
            'Nov':'B31',
            'Dec':'B32'
           }; 

   // make sure event is coming from the drop-down
   if (event.range.getRow() == 7  &&  event.range.getColumn() == 2 )
   {
       var value = event.range.getValue();
       range=sheet.getRange(map[value]);
       sheet.setActiveRange(range);
   }  
}
```

EDIT: Code updated from `if else` construct to `"associative array"` construct (implemented as a JS object initialised with key:value pairs) based on excellent comments from the appropriately named "TheMaster".